# Error propagation through Camel Resequencer

Tags: apache-camel

Consider the following Camel route:

```
from("file://....?moveFailed=/failed")
   .resequence(c).stream()
   .throwException(new Exception());
```

I would expect that the file consumer would move the processed file to the '/failed' folder, because an exception occurred. This is not the case.

Because StreamResequencer uses a new thread to deliver the reordered files (see stacktrace), the exception is never propagated to the file consumer.

```
...
at org.apache.camel.processor.StreamResequencer$Delivery.run(StreamResequencer.java:262)
```

I would appreciate some help/feedback in how to ensure that errors result in the file being moved to failed?

- Option 1: Propagate the exception to the original consumer. However, I have no clue how I would achieve this.
- Option 2: Write a custom '.onException(...)' that moves the file manually, not relying on the file consumer to do this.
- Perhaps there is another, more correct way to set up this route that I didn't think of?

Comment: This is by design how the resequencer works, you would need to use noop=true on the file uri, and move the file yourself after the resequencer. And maybe its just better to write a custom file sorter or file filter that accepts the file in the order you want

Comment: @ClausIbsen Originally we used a file sorter, but due to the amount of files this sorting couldn't keep up. We had to ensure that the order was correct for every file, so we sorted every time we took a single file out. A priority queue (resequencer) is the better option in this case. 

---

I'll follow your advice and go with option 2, moving the file ourselves when needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with option 2 because option 1 isn't feasible. It turned out to work quite well, and the code was still clear. We reworked the route as follows:

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .handled(true)
  .to("direct:moveFile");

from("file://....")
  .setProperty("originalContent", body())
  .resequence(c).stream()
  .to("businessLogicHere")
  .to("direct:moveFile");

from("direct:moveFile")
  .choice()
    .when(property(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT).isNull())
       .setBody(property("originalContent")
       .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("success/${file:onlyname}")
       .to("file://...")
    .otherwise()
       .setBody(property("originalContent")
       .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("failure/${file:onlyname}")
       .to("file://...")
```